# Home button does not terminate program in simulator

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm new to programming and have been using this site for a while now but everything I've had to ask has been answered somewhere but I couldn't find an answer to this:

I am programming a game for the Apple AppStore using Xcode and test it on the iOS Simulator. When I "Build and Run the current Scheme" (the play button on Xcode), I can test out my game, and when I am done I can hit the "Stop the running scheme or application" (the stop button on Xcode), and of course it ends my game.

However, on the iOS Simulator, an icon for my game appears on the main screen along with apple programs such as "safari". When I click this, it enters my game and I can play it fine. However when I click the "Home button" or the "lock button" and re-enter my game, the game is continuing from where I left off; I want the game to end so when I re-enter my game it goes back to its original state.

I was wondering if anyone had a solution to this problem? Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: it is not a problem it is how it suppose to work. you can't kill your app programatically or pressing either home button or lock button. when home button pressed apps enter background and remains there until user open it or kill it. if you want to do something special when your app goes to background you can do it in applicationDidEnterBackground in your app AppDelegate. when home button pressed best thing to do is saving all data as like score where user left etc.

Comment: Just handle appDelegate event: applicationWillResignActive or
applicationDidEnterBackground. However killing application is not good solution. I recommend you to (just!) pasue the game when your app enter background.

Comment: Normal behaviour. You can also add what you want in the App-Info.plist. Something like "Run in background" to force a quit of the app.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit the Home button on your device or simulator, you are simply "backgrounding" the app. That is, you are not quitting or killing the application, you are simply sending it to an 'idle' sort of state.

iOS will automatically kill/quit applications that are in the background if it needs memory, but what you are probably seeing is that you background your app (hit the Home button), and then you tap the game's icon to open it again. This will resume the game where it left off.

When you hit the square (stop) button in Xcode, you are killing/quitting your application. If you run your application from the simulator (not by hitting the play button in Xcode) and you want to quit the app entirely, hit the Home button twice or use the Command+Shift+H shortcut twice to show the app switcher, and then just drag your application's card up.

This will quit the app and make it launch from scratch when you tap the icon in the home screen again.

Comment: As [Larme](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) mentioned in comment you can force your app to quit when user hits Home Button.

Answer (score 0):

Return your game to the original state using this method in the **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}
```

Now when you hit the home button and start the app next time it will be in the state you left it (however you want this to be).